# C# Connection String for a remote SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

I have a database at my dedicated root server. I want to connect to this external database via C# with a program from my computer.

I'm trying with that connection string, but it doesn't work:

```
Data Source=root_ip_adress;Initial Catalog=db_name;User Id=computername\\Administrator;Password=mypassword;
```

Remote connections are enabled in the database.

Error :
"Network-related or instance-specific error connecting to SQL Server The server could not be found or accessed, check that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server allows remote connections." (Provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Waiting process was aborted.) "

Thanks for any help

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: _It doesn't work_ is not a description of your problem. Please be more precise and report the exact error messages received

Comment: You cannot specify a domain account in the connection string. The user and password in that case is a SQL Server account. To connect with Windows authentication, specify `Integrated Security=SSPI` instead. The connection will then be made using the account of the current user.

Comment: @MendaxM. That should go into the question instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to log in first with Management Studio (SSMS)
2. Try removing computername\ from the username
3. make sure this user has access permission to the db. see [principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/principals-database-engine) [create a database user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify a Windows account (domain or local) in the connection string. The user and password in the connection string is interpreted as a SQL Server authenticated account.

To connect with Windows authentication, specify `Integrated Security=SSPI` instead of User ID and password. The connection will then be made using the account of the current user.

Answer (score 0):

While Dan Guzman's answer is correct about Windows authentication, your problem is not there.

The server cannot be reached at all, so it happens **prior** any possible authentication attempt.

The most probable cause of this error is the named instance, i.e. it listen on other port than the default.

Your actions to find the cause are:

- make sure TCP\IP is enabled on server
- ping your server
- check the errorlog to find out the port hich the server is listening
- check this port with telnet
- write the port in your connection string if the port differs from
  1433 or use instance name + SQL Server browser in case of named
  instance